# Show WordPress subcategories if on it

Tags: php, wordpress

I've got 5 categories, one of them has 5 subcategories.

```
<?php
    $cat_object = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $i = $cat_object->term_id;

    while (true) {
        $cat = get_category($i);
        if ($cat->category_parent) {
            $i = $cat->category_parent;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    $parentcat = $i;
    wp_list_categories("depth=2&child_of=$parentcat&title_li=");
?>
```

I have this code to display all categories and subcategories at the same time, but I want to display subcategories only if I'm on the category.

It's like we have:

- 1
- 2

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- 3
- 4

And I want to display only:

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

And if I go to "2" I will see:

- 1
- 2

  - 1
  - 2
  - 3
- 3
- 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

`"depth=2&child_of=$parentcat&title_li="` to

`"depth=2&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li="`

Comment: I've got it. Thank you Billy.

Comment: Cool. What was the problem/solution?

Comment: if (is_category(array(8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14))) {
                    wp_list_categories("depth=2&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li=");
                } else {
                    wp_list_categories("depth=1&child_of=" . $parentcat . "&title_li=");
                }